# How to transfer event data from .on(dragstart) to .on(drop) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to transfer information (in this case data) between an .on(dragstart) event and an .on(drop) event. When I run the following code in Chrome I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>HTML Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: DimGrey;
      }

      .a1 {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .in, .out {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 40%;
        top: 40%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="0" class="a1" style="left:30%;top:40%">
      <div id='y' tabindex="-1" class="out" draggable="true">&#x2299;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="a1" style="left:60%;top:40%">
      <div id='x' class="in">&#x229A;</div>
    </div>
    <script>

      $(".out").on("dragstart", {test:"a"}, function(ev){
      });

      $(".in").on("dragover", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }).on("drop", function(ev) {
        ev.target.append(ev.data.test);
      });


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From my research it seems like data only works in the same event in jQuery, but in vanilla JavaScript drag and drop events do transfer data.
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
// Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent

$(function() {
  var dragged;

  $(".a1").on("dragstart", ".out", {
    test: "a"
  }, function(ev) {
    console.log("DragStart", ev.data.test);
    dragged = ev.target;
    $(dragged).data(ev.data);
  });

  $(".in").on("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }).on("drop", function(ev) {
    ev.target.append($(dragged).data("test"));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: DimGrey;
}

.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.in,
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="0" class="a1" style="left:30%;top:40%">
  <div id='y' tabindex="-1" class="out" draggable="true">&#x2299;</div>
</div>
<div id="1" class="a1" style="left:60%;top:40%">
  <div id='x' class="in">&#x229A;</div>
</div>
```

When you review docs for [.on()][1], you will see:

`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

The *Data to be passed to the handler in `event.data` when an event is triggered,* is designated for the Event callback, not for another event.

We can use `.data()` to attach data to an element. In this way, you can pass in the object, attach it to the element, and when it is dropped, you can collect the data.
[1]: https://api.jquery.com/on/